# More efficient way to assign group for each row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a data frame with more than 1000 columns, and I have a predefined group list. I would like to compare each cell value with the each group boundary and create a new column to assign the group name. I have written `for loops` but it took more than 5 mins to process it. Is there any more efficient way to achieve this? Thanks

Here my data frame

```
Frequency
21.0
18.0    
16.0    
10.0
10.0    
9.0    
10.0    
10.0      
5.0       
8.0
```

And my predefined group list

```
> groups    
[(3, 5), (6, 10), (11, 30)]
```

What I would like to get is

```
Frequency   Group
21.0        11-30
18.0        11-30
16.0        11-30
10.0        6-10
10.0        6-10
9.0         6-10
10.0        6-10
10.0        6-10
5.0         3-5
8.0         6-10
```

Here is my code

```
for i in range(0, len(fre_table["Frequency"])):
    for j in range(0, len(groups)):
        if fre_table["Frequency"][i] >= groups[j][0] and fre_table["Frequency"][i] <= groups[j][1]:
            break
    fre_table['Group'][i] = "{}-{}".format(groups[j][0], groups[j][1])
```

Comment: Use pd.cut: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Establishing the efficiency of the solution suggested by @BallpointBen in the comment section

Data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fre_table = pd.DataFrame({'Index':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
             'Frequency':[21.0, 18.0, 16.0, 10.0, 10.0, 9.0, 10.0, 10.0, 5.0, 8.0]})
groups = [(3, 5), (6, 10), (11, 30)]
```

Time taken by the initial solution: `0.5420`

```
import timeit
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
fre_table['Group'] = 0
for i in range(0, len(fre_table["Frequency"])):
    for j in range(0, len(groups)):
        if fre_table["Frequency"][i] >= groups[j][0] and fre_table["Frequency"][i] <= groups[j][1]:
            break
    fre_table['Group'][i] = "{}-{}".format(groups[j][0], groups[j][1])
elapsed_time = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
```

Time take by the final solution: `0.0043s`

```
import timeit
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(groups)
fre_table['Group'] = pd.cut(fre_table['Frequency'], bins)
elapsed_time = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
```

About a 100 times faster!